# How to find distinct values from a specific index of a generic list

Tags: c#, linq, collections, generic-list

I have a generic list

```
LinkedList<RelationModel> mylist = new LinkedList<RelationModel>();
```

This list fetches output at two index {0} and {1}. There are multiple values at both of the indexes. While debugging, at

```
{0} - the output is     

Foreign             "Store"       --string
ForeignKeyColumn    "addressId"   --string
Primary             "Address"     --string
PrimaryKeyColumn    "addressId"   --string

{1} - the output is 

Foreign             "Address"     --string
ForeignKeyColumn    "countryId"   --string
Primary             "Country"     --string
PrimaryKeyColumn    "countryId"   --string
```

The issue is I have to pick distinct values from the list. For Example-- Here, Store, Address and Country are distinct. How to pick these values in C# code?

The below code fills data into mylist

```
using (var ctx = new TestDBEntities())
            {
                var foreginKeyList = ctx.Database
                .SqlQuery<MetdataModel>(" Select  [PKTABLE_NAME], [PKCOLUMN_NAME],[FKTABLE_NAME],[FKCOLUMN_NAME] from GetMetadata")
                .ToList();
                LinkedList<RelationModel> mylist = new LinkedList<RelationModel>();
                for (int i =0; i < foreginKeyList.Count; i++)
                {

                    var ss = foreginKeyList.Where(p => p.FKTABLE_NAME.Equals(foreginKeyList[i].FKTABLE_NAME)).Select(p => new { p.PKTABLE_NAME, p.PKCOLUMN_NAME }).ToList();
                    foreach(var col in ss)
                    {
                        RelationModel gg = new RelationModel();
                        gg.Foreign = foreginKeyList[i].FKTABLE_NAME;
                        gg.ForeignKeyColumn = foreginKeyList[i].FKCOLUMN_NAME;
                        gg.Primary = col.PKTABLE_NAME;
                        gg.PrimaryKeyColumn = col.PKCOLUMN_NAME;
                        mylist.AddLast(gg);

                    }

                }
```

I need a final list which will have distinct values like

```
mylist.[0]- store
mylist.[1]- address
mylist.[2]- country
```

Comment: on which property do you want the `Distinct`to work on? `Primary` or `Foreign` ? as your resulted list have both?

Comment: Both Primay and Foreign are table names. I want to fetch the distinct table names. As you can see, address is getting repeated at {1}. So, I want to fetch these dynamic distinct values from that output and put them in a generic list. For ex- if address is put in the list at {0}, it shouldn't be added to the list when going through {1} index

Comment: "This list fetches output at two index {0} and {1}." - can you re-write this / explain it more clearly? I take it you don't care about the `KeyColumn` values?

Comment: Nope. I just want to fetch the table names. They are fetched at "Primary" and "Foreign"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `RelationModel` is

```
public class RelationModel {
    public string Foriegn;
    public string ForeignKeyColumn;
    public string Primary;
    public string PrimaryKeyColumn;
}
```

then you can use the following:

```
var ans = mylist.SelectMany(m => new[] { m.Foriegn, m.Primary }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now you can access the elements of `ans` as `ans[0]`, `ans[1]`, etc.

Comment: when I use ans.ToList(); it says "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<string>' "   So, when I write 'ans.[0]' it gives an error. How to resolve this?

Comment: @RahulDev If you add `.ToList()` after `.Distinct()` you should not have this problem.